# How to have follow and unfollow link is user index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

am reading micheal hart ruby on rails tutrial and i have the follow and unfollow button working on the user show page but then i try to add it to the user index page index page i get this error

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

this my form code for the form

```
<% user ||= current_user %>
<div id="follow_form">
<% if current_user.following? user %>
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),html: { method: :delete },remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
<div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Follow", class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

after adding that i still get the same error. the form is rendere  using this  `<%= render @users %>` and that partial contain this `

```
    </div>
    <div class="user-profile-inner">
        <h6 >
        <%= link_to user.name, user %></h4>
        <%= gravatar_all user %>
      <h5><%= user.position %></h5>

        <!-- User button -->
        <div class="user-button">
            <div class="row">

                  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
              <div class="col m6">
                 <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,class: 'waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-4',
```

data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>

```
                  <% end %>


                <div class="col m6">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <%= render "follow_form_user"  %>  </button>

                </div>
                     <div class="col m6">
                         <% unless current_user == @user %>
                         <%= link_to 'Send message', new_message_path(to: user.id), class: 'waves-effect waves-light btn' %>
                         <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

anymore code i need to add on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have `@user` instance variable here, but just `user`. Replace `@user` with `user` here.

Comment: Same error? Please check stacktrace and line of code where the exception is thrown.